# Show that every infinite recursive set is the range of a nondecreasing unbounded recursive function of one variable.

Tags: partial-fractions

I came across this problem and I was not able to solve it: 
**Show that every infinite recursive set is the range of a nondecreasing unbounded recursive function of one variable.**

Also, what would be the case if the function is bounded? 
 Thanks :)

Comment: What can you say about a nondecreasing bounded (integer) function of one variable?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki it's a recursive function ?

Comment: Salma: if it's bounded there's some $N$ such that it can never be greater than $N$.  What can you say about the set of (natural numbers) $\leq N$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki it is infinite ? So $N$ is infinite ?